# Sharing a container in windows azure

Tags: azure, acl, cloud-storage

I'm trying to share a container in windows azure storage but i have some doubts about it. I already read the documentation but i dont know if there is some feature that help me with what i need.

So, my question is: There is some way to share a container with others windows azure storage accounts through java api? What i need is grant read and write permission so that the granting users can uploads data to that container and all can read the others uploads.

Maybe Shared Access Signature feature is what i'm looking for, but i don't understand it correctly.

Thanks in advance,
Regards,
Tiago Oliveira

Answer (score 0):

Your best option may be to set the container to allow public, anonymous reads to fulfill your "all can read" requirement. Then generate shared access signatures that allow you to "grant read and write permission" to other users.

However, additional detail on your scenario (what's driving the requirements and what the clients are) may change this. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, was really helpful :). Can you tell me how can i generate a shared access signature for a specific user, and how he can access my container? i was reading this page http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/introducing-table-sas-shared-access-signature-queue-sas-and-update-to-blob-sas.aspx, but i can't undersand how can i do it :/.

Comment: You can't generate a signature for a specific user. A SAS is like checking a book out of the library, but the book automatically returns to the library at a present time. You may check out the book, but if you leave it somewhere, someone else may pick up the book. But regardless, the book will always return. You may want to check out my response to another thread on SAS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175094/how-to-name-windows-azure-sharedaccessblobpolicy-keys/22177254#22177254